# How to setup multiple apps in Flask that have models with same name?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask project with multiple apps and using Sqlalchemy+Alembic for database, how would I handle the case where the apps have models with same name (for example all of the apps will have User model)? In Django the tables are prefixed with app name so there's no conflicts. Is there some way to do the same here?

Comment: Miguel's solution is the simplest. If you want it so that you don't need to add the prefix to each table name, you could loop over all your models and set the prefix after you've imported them. Otherwise, the answer would probably involve using metaclasses, and be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `__tablename__` in each model to assign a name to each table explicitly:

```
class User1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'app1_users'
    id = db.Column(...)
    # ...

class User2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'app2_users'
    id = db.Column(...)
    # ...
```